# The action you have requested is not allowed - CI 3.0 internet explorer 11

Tags: php, post, continuous-integration, csrf

I have problem with form request in (only) intent explorer 11 (old no check).
Chrome and firefox is good.

Source html form:

```
...
<form action="http://192.168.0.53/users/products/show/41" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token_name" value="5ab6faa347ddf882ff50882c9835cfab" style="display:none;" />
...
```

Config CI 3.0:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = true;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_token_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
```

Codeginiter automatic genere input hidden with csrf key.

Why is this happening?

ps. sorry for my english :/ I try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solution:

in meta tags (header):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
```

change to:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" >
```

And work :)